# Authorising SOAP requests using OAuth2.0 in NuSOAP

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, nusoap

I am using NuSOAP toolkit for SOAP API integration. Now I would like to authorise requests using OAuth2.0. How can we authorise SOAP requests using OAuth2.0 in NuSOAP? I am finding extremely difficult to get a documentation... Thanks in advance.